# The difference between $E-k$ diagram and simplified Energy band digram

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory

I know form the the Kroning-Penny Model the $E-k$ diagram solution which something like this

[image]

or like this

[image]

but While dealing with semiconductors we always draw this energy band diagram

[image]

My question is: Where did this simplified energy band came from? and Why we say that the potential energy of the valence band or conduction band is constant, because from the kroning -penny model the total Energy is a function of the wave vector so the potential energy may change with the wave vector, how can we assume (in the simplified energy band) that it's constant across the whole band?

Comment: The horizontal axis in your bottom picture is typically real space, not momentum.

Comment: @KFGauss, But what makes the whole band have the same potential ?

Comment: They are plotting the top of the valence and bottom of the conduction bands in real space. They don't vary because there are no voltages etc

Comment: @KFGauss, but isn't the potential energy inside the conduction band and the valence band vary from point to point , not constant on the whole matertial  ?

Comment: @KFGauss , how can the potential energy inside the whole conduction band and the 
whole valence band be constant all over the band ?